# Sort divs by data attribute include page range

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I have a results set of data that includes page numbers

```
<div class="results">
   <div class="result" data-pages="1005-1007">
      pp 1005-1007
   </div>
   <div class="result" data-pages="997">
      pp 997
   </div>
   <div class="result" data-pages="1009-1012">
      pp 1009-1012
   </div>
   <div class="result" data-pages="1037-1038">
     pp 1037-1038
  </div>
```

A simple sort would re-order these if they were integers:

```
$('.result').sort(function(a,b){
   return $(a).data('pages') >$(b).data('pages');
}).appendTo('.results')
```

But the ranges throw off the results, unsurprisingly the function above is unhelpful:

```
pp 1005-1007
pp 997
pp 1009-1012
pp 1037-1038
```

How can I use javascript/jquery to reorder these results into something that will give me:

```
pp 997
pp 1005-1007
pp 1009-1012
pp 1037-1038
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craigjb12/CFYnE/63/

Comment: why have you kept the data pages and the text inside the div result different ? Is it necessarily like that ?

Comment: Wow, good question, I made an error pasting this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You canreturn -1 or 1 from the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

```
$('.result').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('pages') > $(b).data('pages') ? -1 : 1;
}).appendTo('.results')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F8pAt/)

Comment: This looked great at first, but adding some more items unfortunately caused a bit of a breakdown: http://jsfiddle.net/craigjb12/rWPTL/

Comment: @Craigjb do you want to sort by the first part only?

Comment: @Arun Great question! I can't think of any cases where just sorting by everything before the hyphen would not work... so yes!

Comment: @Craigjb it seems to a problem with string comparison and my logic was flawed

Comment: @ArunPJohny why have you added the 10 in $(a).data('pages'), 10 <-- this one ?

Comment: @aelor it is the radix parameter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt